# PIC18F2550 Assembly BRA command

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, pic18

Hi I have an question about the BRA command in the PIC18F2550.
The command works according to the datasheet like following:

```
BRA n
-1024 <= n <= 1023
PC + 2 + 2n -> PC
```

But what happens when the PC gets an negative value where will it point in the Program memory then?

Comment: This is a complete guess (hence, not an answer), but my experience with other small controllers is that it will effectively wrap in the memory. This would be an outstanding thing to try out in a simulator with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that the PC Should never get an negative value and if it get that then something is very wrong.